# Should both "affect" and "effect" be correct to fill in this sentence?

Tags: comparison

So I was playing this [quiz](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/10/confusing-words-quiz/) on Oxford Dict where the fourth question asks you to fill in the blank with either **affect** or **effect**:

> Will being around a puppy _____ your allergies?

And I was very skeptical because it looks to me as if both words would suit perfectly.

If I want to say that being around a puppy has an effect or like make something change about my allergic problem, then I would use **affect**.

And if I want to say that being around a puppy merely causes my allergies to happen, then I would use **effect**, as defined by Oxford in this [embedded link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/effect).

It totally depends on what I want to say to choose which one to fill, or am I wrong?

The solution to the quiz, according to Oxford, is **affect**, by the way.

Comment: **effect** is either a noun, which won't work, or a verb which means "to cause something to happen or to occur".  Allergies don't happen, allergic reactions do.  If it said, "...effect an allergic reaction" it would be ok.

Comment: @TRomano Allergy is a response by the body so it feels to me like something that can happen/take place, don't you think? Moreover, **effect** can also be defined as **bring about**; and I think it's quite logical for something to bring about allergy?

Comment: I think very technically speaking, you could use *effect*.  But don't do it.  It is at best a very unusual, stilted way of using *effect*.  And really, being around a puppy doesn't "make your allergies happen", your allergies already existed, and being around a puppy just causes the symptoms.

Comment: Linguistically *allergy* can be understood as a condition that exists over time, whose symptoms manifest themselves as bodily reactions.  Conditions don't *occur* or *happen*, they *exist*. Only those things which can be caused to *occur* can be *effected*.

Comment: But you could say "Will being around a puppy *have an effect on* your allergies?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's any comfort, many native speakers would flip a coin to decide whether to use "affect" or "effect".  That's why they put it in quizzes that challenge English speakers.

In this case, the correct answer would be **affect** since it means, "to produce a change".  For example:

> The bad press affected my previously positive opinion of the political candidate.

meaning that the news *made a change* in my opinion -- which is to say, made it less positive.

"Effect", when used as a verb, is more formal and has the meaning, "to cause to happen" or "bring about".  For example:

> The new president's policies *effected* considerable disruption in government services.

Dog hair or pollen don't "bring about" allergies.  The allergies already exist and are caused by other factors.  So "effect" does not work in the sentence, at least as it is written.  You can, however, say that these irritants "**effect** an allergic **reaction**", but this kind of verbiage is more appropriate to a scientific journal than casual conversation.

Side note:  Since both can be used as a verb, with only subtle differences in meaning, the quiz seems to be less about understanding the differences between the two, and more whether you know that allergens don't *cause* allergies, but instead only *aggravate* them.  Not necessarily a fair test.

Comment: I don't think this answer requires scientific knowledge. But it does require a native sense of **your** and an understanding of the verb **effect**.  Native speakers say that we **have** an allergy or allergies.  The possessive **your** indicates that these allergies already exist. Those things which already  exist cannot be **effected**. They are **affected**.